# Scoping issue when using doParallel

Tags: r, doparallel

I am trying to estimate multiple nonparametric models using the `doParallel` package. My problem though seems to be related to the `np` package. 
Take a look at this reproducible example:

```
library(np)
library(doParallel)

df     <- data.frame(Y = runif(100, 0, 10), X = rnorm(100))
models <- list(as.formula(Y ~ X))

npestimate <- function(m, data) {
  LCLS <- npregbw(m, data = data, regtype = "lc", bwmethod = "cv.ls")
  LLLS <- npregbw(m, data = data, regtype = "ll", bwmethod = "cv.ls")
  # sigt <- npsigtest(LCLS, boot.method = "wild", boot.type = "I")
  return(list(LCLS = LCLS, LLLS = LLLS))
}

cl <- makeCluster(length(models))
registerDoParallel(cl)

results <- foreach(m = models, .packages = "np", .verbose = T) %dopar% 
  npestimate(m, data = df)

stopCluster(cl)
```

As you can see I created a function called `npestimate()` in order to compute different stuff for each model. I commented out one line where I want to run significance tests using `npsigtest`. Usually, `npsigtest` gets the data used by looking in the environment where `npregbw` was called.

But this does not work here. I am not sure why but `npsigtest` just cannot find the data that was used in the two lines of code right above. 
The data is automatically exported to the nodes, so using `.export` in `foreach` is redundant.

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npsigtest` copies pretty much the approach used within `lm` and functions for `lm` objects. It thus has the same potential scoping pitfalls. The issue is the environment associated with the formula:

```
environment(models[[1]])
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

It's easy to fix:

```
npestimate <- function(m, data) {
  environment(m) <- environment()
  LCLS <- npregbw(m, data = data, regtype = "lc", bwmethod = "cv.ls")
  LLLS <- npregbw(m, data = data, regtype = "ll", bwmethod = "cv.ls")
  sigt <- npsigtest(LCLS, boot.method = "wild", boot.type = "I")
  return(list(LCLS = LCLS, LLLS = LLLS))
}
```

I actually often prefer `eval(bquote())` constructs because of such issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did fix my problem. What do you exactly mean with `eval(bquote())` constructs?

Comment: Thanks for clarification! :)

Comment: One more question: now `npsigtest` finds the data. But when there are rows containing `NA`, which are filtered out by `npregbw`, `npsigtest` does not know which rows were obmitted. Usually it does know that.

Comment: Doing so within `npestimate` or prior to it (but within `foreach`) does not work as well.